# jQuery Mobile swipe, how to hold/ stop change page event?

Tags: android, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, swipe

I am new to **jQuery Mobile 1.4.5**, when I try to implement `changePage()` triggered by `swipeleft`, it works perfect with following code:

```
    $("#mypage").on("swipeleft", function(e){
        log("swipeleft");
        if(event.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
        {
            $.mobile.changePage('#mypage2', {transition: "slide"});
            event.handled = true;
        }
        return false; 
    });
```

However, once the `changePage()` event is triggered, it can't go back until the next page is completely showed. I was wondering is it possible to do like other "swipe to change page" function e.g. Facebook slide to show friend list. I can slide to show part of target page, and the edge of page is just followed where my finger is. Instead of changing whole page

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I mean while swiping left the current page, the target page shows more from the right; when swiping right, the target page shows less. Unless I swipe whole page

Comment: no you cant do that. once the animation has started then thats' it. You need something like  Iscroll for that functionality you want -- http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5 -- something like this -- https://jonathanstark.com/labs/iscroll/examples/horizontal-scroll/ -- but make those columns into full page size and use the snap to page option. That should give you that effect